# Bar plot with ranges in the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have loads of rows of different years like this:

```
1926
2019
1783
1239
2015
...
```

I would like to group into several bins that would go on the x-axis and the y-axis would represent the number of years that are part of this group. Desired output: [image: Output]

```
q1 = np.percentile(foundation_year_cleaned,25)
q3 = np.percentile(foundation_year_cleaned, 75)
IQR = q3-q1
wid = 2 * IQR / (len(foundation_year_cleaned) ** (1. / 3))
bins = np.arange(np.amin(foundation_year_cleaned),np.amax(foundation_year_cleaned),wid)
figure(num=None, figsize=(14, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.grid(linestyle='-', linewidth='0.3', color='gray')
histo = plt.hist(foundation_year_cleaned,bins)
```

My code until now but it does not accomplish what I would like to obtain and not sure how to change it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Currently neither is your code runnable, nor is there any data which people can work with. This makes giving a solution rather time consuming. Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What does your code accomplish? You can use `numpy` to get your histogram and then use this example for a horizontal bar plot https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barh.html